# Rewriting a select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a rather simple (I think) question at hand. The example tables and the result I need are provided below (in reality those tables containt much more columns and data, I jest left what is relevant). There is also the query which returns exactly what I need. However, I dont like rather crude way in which it works (I dont like subqueries in general). The question is, how can I rewrite the query so it will automatically react to more columns appearing in TABLE2 in the future? Right now if the "z" column would be added to TABLE2, I need to modify each query in the code and add one more relevant subquery. I just want the select to read the entire content of TABLE2 and translate the id numbers to corresponding strings from TABLE1.

TABLE1

```
-----------------
id      |x      |
-----------------
567     |AAA    |
345     |BBB    |
341     |CCC    |
827     |DDD    |
632     |EEE    |
503     |FFF    |
945     |GGG    |
234     |HHH    |
764     |III    |
123     |JJJ    |
-----------------
```

TABLE2

```
-------------------------
id      |x      |y      |
-------------------------
1       |123    |341    |
2       |567    |632    |
3       |345    |945    |
4       |764    |503    |
5       |234    |827    |
-------------------------
```

THE RESULT I NEED

```
-----------------
A       |B      |
-----------------
JJJ     |CCC    |
AAA     |EEE    |
BBB     |GGG    |
III     |FFF    |
HHH     |DDD    |
-----------------
```

### The query I have

```
SELECT
(SELECT `x` FROM `TABLE1` WHERE `TABLE2`.`x` LIKE `TABLE1`.`id` LIMIT 1) as A,
(SELECT `x` FROM `TABLE1` WHERE `TABLE2`.`y` LIKE `TABLE1`.`id` LIMIT 1) as B
FROM `TABLE2` ORDER BY `id` DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to restructure your data model:

Instead of:

```
-------------------------
id      |x      |y      |
-------------------------
1       |123    |341    |
2       |567    |632    |
3       |345    |945    |
4       |764    |503    |
5       |234    |827    |
-------------------------
```

You would have:

```
----------------------
col_id      |col     |
----------------------
1           |x       |
2           |y       |
----------------------

---------------------------
id      |col_id  |col_val |
---------------------------
1       |1       |123     |
1       |2       |341     |
2       |1       |567     |
2       |2       |632     |
etc
---------------------------
```

Probably not worth the hassle (you would effectively need to pivot when you're accessing multiple columns at a time) but it would allow you to do the query that you want across all current and future columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with a plain select.

What you can do is creating a view with the translated values. You still have to modify the view when the original table is changed but your queries don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic sql statements, but still you can use the dynamic statements only if you are sure that table 2 will have the columns of same type like x and y(Apart from id).

Let me know if you are not sure how to write it.

All the best.